# Current trend in testing models in a rails3 + datamapper application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3, shoulda

What is the current trend for testing models in a Rails3+DataMapper application. I want to use RSpec but sorely miss the concise testing provided by shoulda macros. Question - Is there a way of getting the best of both worlds, ie. a nice dsl for testing and the brevity of shoulda macros, which can be used to test datamapper models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [remarkable](http://github.com/remarkable/remarkable). That will do exactly what you want :)

UPDATE [9/8/2012] : Unfortunately while it is still possible to use remarkable in rails 3, it is still the same old 4.0.0.0pre version. So on now rails projects I generally use [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/) instead. Not as extended, but covers most stuff, and it is maintained :)